# Why do words like "herrschen" have two r?

Tags: spelling

What are the historical, orthographical  and etymological reasons for this? I checked Wiktionary says it is from Middle High German *hērschen* with one r.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *herrschen* is derived from the noun *der Herr* (mister, master, lord). *Der Herr* was the leading person of a group. Among christians *der Herr* is even used as a synonym for god (very similar to the English *lord*).

The verb *herrschen* means *to govern, to rule, to dominate* (*to dominate* is derived from latin *dominus* = German *Herr* = English *lord*)

And it is true. In Middle High German (MHG) the verb had only one R and a long E:

> hērschen

But this is the [MHG version of *Herr*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herr):

> hēr

So both words was written similar at same epochs.

In German the number of written consonants at the end of a syllable indicate the length of the preceding vowel. Two or more consonants indicate a short vowel, and a double consonant counts as two consonants. Only one consonant or no consonant at all indicates a longe vowel. (There are exceptions, but this rule is true for the vast majority of German words)

So, when the former long vowel E becomes short over the centuries, this change of pronunciation induces a change in spelling: the number of written consonants after that vowel needs to be increased, and since there is only one spoken consonant it has to be written twice.

Comment: In other words, the orthographical reason is that it's pronounced this way. The historical rason is a sound change that occurs in some words and doesn't in others. [Here](https://duepublico.uni-duisburg-essen.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-22103/Lautwandel%2009.pdf) it says that long vowels becoming short "especially happens" before /ht/ and /r/+consonant, which, funnily enough, is fulfilled by _hērschen_, but not by _hēr_. (Although of course the word often behaves like a consonant.)